# How do I prevent application calling datastore_v3.next() when calling get_multi?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, appstats

I'm running a keys_only query, which fetches 20 results.

```
result_keys, cursor, more = ActivityIndex.query(cls.followers  == key)\
                                        .order(-cls.date_created)\
                                        .fetch_page(num_results,
                                                    start_cursor = cursor,
                                                    keys_only=True)
```

I then get the parents of the activityIndex objects:

```
keys = []
for k in result_keys:
    for pair in k.parent().pairs():
        keys.append(ndb.Key(pairs=[pair]))

activities_related = ndb.get_multi(keys)
```

I thought this would be quick, because I was getting a batch of objects by key. However, the query seems call `datastore_v3.Next`, which according to the [appstats docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appstats) is "bad", and takes up a significant portion of the execution time.

> Avoiding unnecessary Next calls may speed up your app!

Appstats for the above query (with get_multi call)
[image: Appstats view with get_multi enabled]

Appstats for the above query but without call get_multi (short time for next() to respond).
[image: short time for next to respond]

Why does the `datastore_v3.next()` call take so long to execute when calling `get_multi()`? Does it depend on the number of results get_multi will return? Some of the objects returned in get_multi have list properties (with max 10 items in a list), would this play a role in the performance?

To avoid this issue, would it be better to change the design and fetch the required entities in tasklets? Any other suggestions?

**Edit:**

A bit more information about what I am trying to do:
I have an activity stream in my application, which displays all user activity e.g. Rob commented on Picture etc.
To display this information, I thought I'd need the User object and the Picture Object to build up the activity description and information to display. I set all these objects' keys as parents of `ActivityIndex`. So from the above query, `ndb.get_mult(keys)` would be fetching the Activity, User and Picture objects. **The keys list could contain 50 keys or more**, so would this possibly be the cause of the long `datastore_v3.Next` call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you doing this in the dev_appserver?  (I hope not, because its performance is completely unrelated to that of the production environment, and we'd all be wasting our time discussing this.)

Looks like there's something fishy going on.  ISTR that the Next call is scheduled asynchronously, and in some cases is not actually needed.  That would explain that even though you are not overlapping the calls, the first chart shows Next overlapping the memcache get call.

But still, there shouldn't be that much of a delay.  Are you doing extra stuff you're not showing before calling get_multi()?

BTW what you are doing with the pairs looks over-complicated.  If there are any parents that have more than one pair, this will produce invalid keys.  I *think* there is only one level of parents and you just want to get those -- if that's so, this should be sufficient:

```
keys = [k.parent() for k in result_keys]
```

Finally, see issue 118: http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=118 -- we measured the trick you seem to be attempting and it is only worth it if your hit rate is really high.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Guido. I was doing this on live server. Regarding extra stuff; only the request handler and fetching user_key from session. Regarding the pairs over-complication; I've edited my question to explain what I was trying to do with the pairs. However, I think I need to redesign and possibly fetch these additional entities in tasklets or denormalize.

Comment: If the keys list contained more than 50keys, would this cause long datastore_v3.Next() call?

Comment: IIUC you're abusing the parent key pairs -- the actual parent doesn't actually exist.  This is not how parent keys are supposed to be used and I have no idea how this affects the datastore performance.  And if you really have 50 pairs in one key, that will appear as a very deeply nested and very long (and meaningless) key to the datastore, so it is possible that it indeed requires multiple batches to fetch the results.  I think you ought to rethink this.  Maybe projection queries can help you?

Comment: The parent keys would contain 5 keys max, but it did seem to affect the datastore retrieval time negatively! I remodeled to use single parent, that had the data flattened in the parent entity (for fast retrieval), which took the time down drastically. Perhaps I should remodel further to only use single entity with projection. Thanks for your help.