# AppEngine NDB query and datastore_v3.Next()

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a few AppEngine operations that take more time than expected, so I've been looking at the trace logs on the GAE console to get some insights.

One of them consists in a simple query to sort entities, such as

```
(data, cursor, more) = query.order(-cls.created).fetch_page(RESULTS_PER_PAGE, start_cursor=cursor)
```

but according to the logs, and if I understand the trace correctly (screenshot below), the operation run 2 queries: one to get the data (RunQuery), one to find if there's more data (Next). Neither take too much time, but there's a 600ms delay between both.

I'm wondering why this delay both is too long? I've seen some issues about Next() where queries took longer ([How do I prevent application calling datastore_v3.next() when calling get_multi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192395/how-do-i-prevent-application-calling-datastore-v3-next-when-calling-get-multi)), but the time for Next() in my case is very minimal. The bottleneck seems to be the time between both. This happens in lots of cases - the previous NDB query is just an example.

So:

1. Can I avoid calls to Next() or
2. Can I minimize the delay between RunQuery and Next()

I'm using a standard instance, and don't have any specific setup in my app.yaml file, besides an inbound warmup.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

use `.fetch()` instead of `.fetch_page()` ... the former fetches up to a limit and stops... it doesn't return any information about whether there are more results

Comment: Yes, that's also what I was advise on a separate conversation - as there's no way to control the latency between the RunQuery() and Next(). However, it won't work if I need to know when I have more results (hence the use of fetch_page())

Comment: consider using a query iterator... there is a special `probably_has_next()` call which uses some shortcuts for efficiency, but I'm not an authority on it:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#iterators

Answer (score 0):

This is just speculation, but I think the reason that query results are broken into multiple chunks (`.Next`) is because of the size of each chunk.  If you can reduce the size of your entities or use [Projection queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/projectionqueries) to shrink the results, you may see better performance.